# How to write a custom udta atom with AVAssetWriter?

Tags: ios, mp4, avassetwriter

I'm using `AVAssetWriter` on iOS 9.3 SDK to write an AAC packaged in MP4 container. Pretty standard stuff. It is working well.

However, now I need to add an atom contained in the `udta` atom (called `mine` for this example), so I have done this:

```
AVAssetWriter * writer =....  

NSData * valueData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:obj options:0 error:nil];

AVMutableMetadataItem * item = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];  
item.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeUserData; //udta  
item.key = @"mine";  
item.value = valueData;

writer.metadata = @[item];  

[writer startWriting];  
...
```

And then in the end, the udta atom doesn't appear at all in the output file. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue. If you create your asset writer in the pure MP4 (`AVFileTypeMPEG4`) mode, then custom metadata seems to be dropped on the floor silently. The solution is to use the QuickTime container file type:

```
AVAssetWriter * writer = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:url fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:nil];
```